# How to read/write file with XUL?

Tags: javascript, file-io, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I'm using xul to code a firefox extension, so I need to read/write from local file. How to create for example file *"temp.txt"* in the following directory *"c:/data"* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for those who are interested:

```
getLocalDirectory : function() { 
    let directoryService = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIProperties); 
    let localDir = directoryService.get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile); 
    localDir.append("FolderName"); 
    if (!localDir.exists() || !localDir.isDirectory())  
        localDir.create(Ci.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0774); 
    return localDir; 
}, 

writeFile: function(data) {
    let myFile = lbbs.files.getLocalDirectory(); 
    myFile.append("FileName.txt"); 
    if ( myFile.exists() == false ) 
         myFile.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0774); 
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm"); 
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm"); 
    var ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(myFile) 
    var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"]. 
    createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter); 
    converter.charset = "UTF-8"; 
    var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(data); 
    NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(status) { 
        if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status))  
            return; 
    });
},

readFile: function() {
    let myFile = lbbs.files.getLocalDirectory(); 
    myFile.append("FileName.txt"); 
    if (myFile.exists() == false) 
        myFile.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0774); 
    var data = ""; 
    var fstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream); 
    var cstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream); 
    fstream.init(myFile, -1, 0, 0); 
    cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); 
    let (str = {}) { 
        let read = 0; 
        do { 
            read = cstream.readString(0xffffffff, str); 
            data += str.value; 
        } while (read != 0); 
    } 
    cstream.close();  
    return data; 
},
```

The file is now created in: %USER_PROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\FireFox\Profiles\aamu4bzq.default\FolderName\FileName.txt

Answer (score 6):

XUL is a mark-up language, you use it to create a user interface. To do things like writing to files you would use [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM). Everything else can be found in the documentation:

- [Creating an nsIFile object using FileUtils module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#The_File_constructor)
- [Writing to a file using FileUtils and NetUtil modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Writing_to_a_file)

General documentation: [FileUtils.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm), [NetUtil.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm), [File I/O code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO)

Comment: Thanks, but how to specify the path of the created file ?

Comment: @AshrafBashir: From the first link above: `var f = new FileUtils.File("c:\\data");`

Answer (score 1):

I think there will be problem when creating the folder outside the application base directory.
For example :- if you want to create a folder inside C:\TEMP it may fail

Comment: Yes, you are right, access is only restricted to the given path.