# XUL: Accessing Hotmail Message sender field. Modify its appearance

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul

I am new to Add-on development.

I am writing a Firefox extension for Hotmail using XUL tutorial. My knowledge of Javascript is pretty limited. My Firefox extension must do the following:

1. When the user opens a received message in MSN Hotmail to read it, locate and read the sender's email address.
2. Verify whether this email address is on a list. The list is stored in a simple text file in the local file system. The Add-on must read the list into memory. (I've read this is difficult with Javascript due to security concerns).
3. Depending on whether the address is in the list, modify the appearance of the "sender" field (I was thinking of changing the background color to green if it exists and red if it does not). The list is supposed to be a group of "secure" senders.

I don't want to use other Add-ons like Greasemonkey, since I believe it would be overkill and I want to learn how this would be done behind curtains.

1. Any general guides or pointers to specific documents which would help me understand how to achieve all this would be REALLY appreciated.
2. Which mechanism is best to perform the text-file-reading part? I've read about FileReader objects, or fopen() function, XMLHttpRequest(), and I am confused which is the best route. The file is guaranteed to be a simple text stored in the local filesystem.

I have been looking through the documentation and so far I have only a limited Add-on with a listener that can display a message when a page is loaded. If somebody can help me narrow my search I would be grateful.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of questions in there.

The best place to reference when developing an addon is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). You may also find help here on Stackoverflow's previous answers, and probably the best way to learn is to find an addon that does something similar to what you are doing, [see the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745151/1385896) and see how they did it.

For reading/writing to a file, you can check [this question on that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9667445/1385896).

Having that, you have to make sure you are on the desired page. You can get the current tab url with:

```
gBrowser.currentURI.spec
```

Then you see if the element that you are trying to style is on the page (meaning you are on the message window), and then you style it they way you want.

Hope this gives you some idea, but to get better and faster answers for next time, try to isolate a problem and ask a specific question about it. The scope of this question is a bit broad.