# Current info on obtaing Firefox extension source code

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've searched here and tried many of the suggestions but things seems to have changed since these posts were answered. Is there new information on how to look at the source code of an extension *directly*?  By *directly* I mean not through some other add-in.

At the moment I am on a machine running Windows XP and Firefox 23.0.1.

When I go to any extension page the "download" button changes to "install" in an instant and no right-clicking or options in the dialog gives me the opportunity to **save rather than install** the plug-in.  I've tried this many times and many different ways.

When I drill down to the ...\Application Data\ ... directories I am finding what just looks like config and data files -- no source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i usually do is go to that extension's page in google chrome and it will show this:

[image]

You click "download anyway" and then change the file extension from xpi to zip and extract it.

Hope it helps

EDIT:

Either in Firefox or Chrome you can also right click on the button like in the following image and click `Save Link As`:

[image]

Comment: Yes. That works too. On Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason Arbalest was telling that he couldn't get the right click working, but it works for me also.