# Open source firefox addon code to learn best coding practices

Tags: javascript, coding-style, open-source, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Learning to write firefox addons I would like to improve the coding style and avoid bad coding practices.

I'm using the mozilla addon-sdk-1.14 and I am looking for the reference of an open source firefox addon, which code is accessible (for example on github), so that I can get inspiration and an idea of how it "should" look like in the "real world".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All extensions have their code available for you to look at. You just:

1. download the xpi,
2. change the xpi extension to zip,
3. extract and see the code inside.

To download the xpi, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18745151/1385896) for some instructions.