# Export Firefox addon source code, including historical versions?

Tags: version-control, firefox-addon

How can one export a Firefox Addon's source code, including all prior versions?

For example the [versions page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/versions/) for Lazarus Form Recovery shows back to v2.04 for [downloading .xpi files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744550/current-info-on-obtaing-firefox-extension-source-code/), but if you follow on into *view source* the archive goes as far back as [0.9.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/files/compare/27517...27633/#top).

The intent is to revive a dormant extension on Github/Bitbucket/... and it would be good to have the history to work with and not just the latest snapshot. It would also be honourable to carry on the name of the original contributors (assuming something like "commit" messages can be retrieved too).